# Background images using mpdf

Tags: drupal, mpdf, print-module

I have a local environment in Drupal 7 and I am using the Print module with the mPDF library.

When I apply a background local image to an element in the PDF it doesn't show, I don't have a red ex indicating that it cannot find it, but when I call

```
$mpdf->showImageErrors = true;
```

my error log tells me that my PDF cannot find the image, I even put the whole link in the background-image property and still, nothing works.
The image is there if I try accessing it in the browser it shows. If I use a link to a random image from google, it works.

Is there something from Drupal preventing access to the image's path?

LATER EDIT:

So this is my CSS & HTML:

```css
.field-name-body blockquote {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  background-image: url("https://local-website.dd:8443/profiles/local/themes/bootstrap_subtheme/img/pdf-icons/quote.png");
  /*background-image: url("/<?php //print drupal_get_path('theme', 'bootstrap_subtheme')?>/img/pdf-icons/quote.png");*/
  background-position: 24px 24px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 24px;
  border: none;
  color: #25a898;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 17px;
  margin: 24px 0;
  padding: 24px 24px 24px 52px;
}
```

```html
<div class="field field-name-body field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden">
  <div class="field-items">
    <div class="field-item even">
      <div class="field-item even">

        <blockquote><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec risus nibh, mattis sed mi tincidunt, porta blandit nibh. Maecenas vulputate imperdiet augue, a tempus nulla venenatis vitae. Etiam rhoncus laoreet luctus. Phasellus dolor justo, tincidunt a eleifend vel, ornare nec dolor.</p>
        </blockquote>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am not doing anything special, my image resides in the path I specified because I can see it locally when I access that address.

The PHP code is the code that resides in the [Print module](https://www.drupal.org/project/print). I only added the showImageErrors line. Images that are added by a content editor are visible, images added in HTML manually or CSS aren't.

```js
function print_pdf_mpdf_print_pdf_generate($html, $meta, $paper_size = NULL, $page_orientation = NULL) {
  module_load_include('inc', 'print', 'includes/print');

  $pdf_tool = explode('|', variable_get('print_pdf_pdf_tool', PRINT_PDF_PDF_TOOL_DEFAULT));
  // Version 7 of the mpdf library uses a composer autoloader.
  // Also there no longer is way to truly detect the library version, so this
  // seems like the best alternative.
  $mpdf_version_7_plus = strpos($pdf_tool[1], 'autoload.php') !== FALSE;
  if (empty($paper_size)) {
    $paper_size = variable_get('print_pdf_paper_size', PRINT_PDF_PAPER_SIZE_DEFAULT);
  }
  if (empty($page_orientation)) {
    $page_orientation = variable_get('print_pdf_page_orientation', PRINT_PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION_DEFAULT);
  }
  $images_via_file = variable_get('print_pdf_images_via_file', PRINT_PDF_IMAGES_VIA_FILE_DEFAULT);

  $config = array();
  if ($mpdf_version_7_plus) {
    $config['tempDir'] = drupal_realpath('public://print_pdf/print_pdf_mpdf/');
  }
  else {
    // Deprecated since mpdf v7.x.
    if (variable_get('print_pdf_autoconfig', PRINT_PDF_AUTOCONFIG_DEFAULT)) {
      if (!defined('_MPDF_TTFONTDATAPATH')) {
        define('_MPDF_TTFONTDATAPATH', drupal_realpath('public://print_pdf/print_pdf_mpdf/ttfontdata/'));
      }
      if (!defined('_MPDF_TEMP_PATH')) {
        define('_MPDF_TEMP_PATH', drupal_realpath('public://print_pdf/print_pdf_mpdf/tmp/'));
      }
    }
  }

  $tool_path = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . $pdf_tool[1];
  if (file_exists($tool_path)) {
    require_once $tool_path;
  }
  else {
    watchdog('print_pdf', 'Configured PDF tool does not exist at path: %path', array('%path' => $tool_path), WATCHDOG_ERROR);
    throw new Exception("Configured PDF tool does not exist, unable to generate PDF.");
  }

  $format = ($page_orientation == "landscape") ? $paper_size . "-L" : $paper_size;

  // Try to use local file access for image files.
  $html = _print_access_images_via_file($html, $images_via_file);

  // Set document information.
  if ($mpdf_version_7_plus) {
    $config['mode'] = 'utf-8';
    $config['format'] = $format;
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf($config);
  }
  else {
    $mpdf = new mPDF('UTF-8', $format);
  }

  if (isset($meta['name'])) {
    $mpdf->SetAuthor(strip_tags($meta['name']));
  }
  $mpdf->SetCreator(variable_get('site_name', 'Drupal'));

  $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
  // Try to recover from any warning/error.
  ob_clean();

  return $mpdf->Output('', 'S');
}
```

Comment: Show your HTML and PHP code. No one is able to troubleshoot anything without it. Do you call mPDF from a server, or from a cli?

Comment: @Finwe I have added more information to the post if it helps, everything happens locally using the print module.

Comment: Provided you don't have a HTTP to HTTPS redirect, if you use the HTTP protocol to display your local image (instead of HTTPS) does that work?

Comment: @JakeJackson it sadly does not. What is frustrating is that, if I print instead of PDF generate, it works, it shows with both HTTP and HTTPS, it works even without specifying the exact path, but on PDF nothing.